# MS Access Giving #Name? Error On SQL SP Fed Forms In Some Conditions

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have a series of SP I am calling to populate my Access form.  These are all called along the same code line being typical:

```vb
Public Sub cssLoadAllJobs(lngCID As Long, frm As Form)
    'See methods and notes under cssLoadClient
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset

    With rst
       Set .ActiveConnection = gcn
       .Source = "EXEC mysp_ActiveJobsForClient " & Nz(lngCID) 'Runs sp with parameter
       .LockType = adLockOptimistic
       .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
       .Open
    End With

    Set frm.Recordset = rst

    Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

These are all working fine and no issue with them.

However on my main form I am loading several of these in succession something like Client, Site and Jobs.

For the jobs I have two different SP.  One is filtered down by client and then by site and then by equipment on this site.  The other is only filtered by the Client.

What is happening is if I load the one with loads of filters into the Main Form the main form works fine.  However if I load the jobs only filtered by CLient the main form is throwing `#Name?` on all the client records fields and the job subform fields are also all sent to `#Name?`.

Thinking this should be simple to diagnose I commented out the line loading the Job subform and all is fine.  If I then add the code back in for the full filtered subform then the main form works okay.

Not to be beaten, as after all this must be a simple error, I made a copy of the job subform and loaded it with the only filtered by Client and it shows the exact records no issue.

To try and make this clearer:

- SP1 = Filtered by client
- SP2 = Filtered by Client AND Filtered By Site AND Filtered By Equipment
- Mainform with SP2 Works
- Mainform with SP1 `#Name?`
- Subform load as Form SP1 Works
- Subform Load as Form SP2 Works

I guess an easy test is to create a new subform and swap them but...Why?

Comment: Don't declare ADODB objects `As New`, that makes them auto-instantiated. Add `Debug.Print rst Is Nothing` at the end of the procedure, you'll see why.

Comment: Consider using an `ADODB.Command`, and using an actual `ADODB.Parameter` instead of stitching executable SQL statement parts together - that's a very common cause of bugs, *and* it's a serious security vulnerability. See "SQL injection attack" for more info.

Comment: But why bother with all that extra code? Just bind the access form to the linked table. If you open the form with a where clause such as "ID = " & lnCID, then Access  will achieve the same performance, and do so without all that extra code and work (trying to save world poverty here). You not achieve better performance here by using that store proc compared to a simple linked table. And that simply linked table allows the form without extra coding to update the table.  So it not at all clear why you using a store proc and all this extra work.

Comment: Picked up 15 seconds in load time with this approach.  I understand what is being said.  But it isn't working for this specific need.